# Append function not working with no errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a car economy bot and lots of my friends were requesting unlimited car slots but when I use append nothing changes, it doesn't append "new" and it doesn't give an error.

```
if option == None and amount == None:
    for item in users[str(user.id)]["cars"]:
        em.add_field(name=f"{index} . {item['car']}", value = f'.', inline = False)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    return

if option == 'store' or option == 'park':
    new = {"car": "test again"}
    users[str(user.id)]["cars"].append(new)
    await ctx.send('Done!')
```

This is my code the `option == None` part is to check the cars

Comment: Are you sure it's getting into the `if` block? Add a `print()` call.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry , im new do you mind explaining a little further?

Comment: Put `print(users[str(user.id)]["cars"])` after you call append. Do you see the added car?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Barmar yes it shows , but it doesn't work in the ```if option == None```

Comment: @Barmar the added car deletes after the if command

Comment: The problem isn't in this code then. Are you sure the `if option == None` code is running after you append?

Comment: @Barmar after the append it prints the added car and then when use the command again it deletes it

Comment: That's what you said before, and I already responded.

Comment: It's not being deleted in this code, it's happening somewhere else.

Comment: Are all the cars being deleted, or just this one?

Comment: @Barmar just one

Comment: Find all the places that modify `users[str(user.id)]["cars"]` and add `print()` calls so you can see what order they're happening in. It must be different from what you expect.